# Strange behaviour of the thread library

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, inputstream, outputstream

I don't know whether this topic is related to the std::thread library or streams. Have a look at the following example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void read(){
    int bar;
    std::cout << "Enter an int: ";
    std::cin >> bar;
}

void print(){
    std::cout << "foo";
}

int main(){
    std::thread rT(read);
    std::thread pT(print);
    rT.join();
    pT.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't care if it will print the "foo" string before or after executing the the read() function. What bothers me is the fact, that when it asks for input before executing the print() function, it actually hangs the execution. I have to click "enter" or feed the std::cin with some data in order to see the "foo" string. Below you can see a three possible scenarios of how this program behaves:

```
1.
>> Enter an int: //here I've clicked enter
>> foo
>> 12 //here I've written "12" and clicked enter
//end of execution

2.
>> fooEnter an int: 12 //here I've written "12" and clicked enter
//end of execution

3.
>> Enter an int: 12 //here I've written "12" and clicked enter
>> foo
//end of execution
```

As you can see, sometimes I have to click enter to see the "foo" string. In my opinion it should be printed every time since it has been launched in a seperate thread. Maybe the std::cin is somehow blocking the std::cout? If so then what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is completely normal, output to `std::cout` is buffered by default. `cout` is tied to `cin` so when you start reading from `cin` or press enter the `cout` buffer gets flushed and appears on the screen.

What probably happens is the first thread writes its output, which gets buffered, then it waits for input, which flushes the output buffer (so you see `"Enter an int:"`) then the second thread writes its output, but it sits in the buffer until the input is read, when the output gets flushed again.

You can force the second thread to output immediately by flushing its buffer manually:

```
 std::cout << "foo" << std::flush;
```

This will probably result in either `"fooEnter an int:"` or `"Enter an int:foo"` but you should not need to press Enter before `"foo"` appears.

Comment: `std::endl` is an alternative, as that's basically `\n' + std::flush`